# Running Jmeter for Https app with single user for multiple times through Loop controller

Tags: jmeter

[Attached is the snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbcg0.png)I am trying to run jmeter for single user with value of 10 in loop controller , I first login into the app and then subsequently uses the CSRF token accordingly for future request .The login is always successful and generates CSRF token, But when i try to use CSRF token for future request , I get unauthorized HTTP 401 reponse code , when running with value 10 in loop controller for single user , the same works when i try to run single user with value 1 in loop controller , Any idea how to fix this? (Note :- All this is present in same thread Group)

Comment: Post hiw your test plan looks and maybe instead of loop use can use 10 threads in thread group

Comment: @user7294900 Attached the snap to the post

Answer (score 1):

Well-behaved JMeter test should be able to loop single user without any problem, most likely you have a problem with your test design or mismatch with the application under test behaviour. General recommendation would look like:

1. First of all switch to iterations on Thread Group level, JMeter configuration elements don't respect iterations originated from elsewhere as "iterations"

   [image: JMeter Iterations Thread Group level]
2. Add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan
3. Run your test with 1 user and 2 loops
4. Inspect request and response details, identify missing/extra/different parameters and fix them. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more details on JMeter test troubleshooting techniques.

Blind shot: your test includes login request and the virtual user is already logged in therefore it doesn't require login on 2nd loop. In this case you have 2 options:

- Put the logic which needs to be executed only 1 time under [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
- If you use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) be aware that `Clear cookies each iteration` works only on Thread Group-level iterations

Comment: adding Iterations to the Loop count at the Thread Group Level instead of having Loop controller in the Thread Group, has increased the failures